# Date format in Excel for SQL

Tags: sql, excel

I would like to generate some SQL scripts using Excel's `CONCAT` function, but column with `Date` type is entered as number in script and I need date for SQL.

Here is a screenshot showing the troubles:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `TEXT()` to format your date properly, :

```
TEXT([@ActualCloseDate], "dd.mm.YYYY hh:MM")
```